# Execute code on jquery mobile after page loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I have a `multipage-site` where I load an external page html ( the framework do the ajax call ). 
After the load of the page I would execute some code I wrote (below). 
This code works fine when I open my page directly, but doesn't work if I reach the page through the jquery navigation.
Any ideas? Thanks

```
function valorijson(cognome){
    var tennista;               
    for(var i=0; i<players.all.length; i++){
        tennista = players.all[i];
        console.log(tennista.cognome);
        if (cognome == tennista.cognome){
            $(".cognome").append(tennista.cognome);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function(){
            $(".trigger-tennista").on("click", "*", function(event){
                var cognome;
                cognome = $(event.target).closest(".trigger-tennista").attr("data-cognome");
                console.log(cognome); // ok fino qui
                $(".single-tennista-container").load("../single-player.html", function(){ // ok caricamento file
                    valorijson(cognome);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** 
I change my code in this, it works but it fires more than one time!

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(){
        $(function(){
            $(".trigger-tennista").on("click", "*", function(event){
                alert("i");
              var cognome;
              cognome = $(event.target).closest(".trigger-tennista").attr("data-cognome");
              console.log(cognome); // ok fino qui
              $(".single-tennista-container").load("../single-player.html", function(){ // ok caricamento file
                valorijson(cognome);
              });
          });
        });
  });
```

**UPDATE 2: PARTIAL WORKING CODE**

```
   $(document).on("pagecreate", "#splashpage", function(){
    var popup = $(".single-tennista-container");
    $(document).on("click", ".trigger-tennista", function(event){       
        var close = $(".close");
        var cognome;
        cognome = $(event.target).closest(".trigger-tennista").attr("data-cognome");
        popup.load("../single-player.html", function(){ // ok caricamento file
            valorijson(cognome);
            popup.removeClass("outsidepopup").addClass("insidepopup");

        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".close", function(){
        popup.removeClass("insidepopup").addClass("outsidepopup");
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the pagecontainer load event: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-load

Comment: @ezanker something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qdsenjgL/2/)? If yes, doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have DOM elements with class .trigger-tennista in each page, you can use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to create the click handler once when the first jQM page is created (change `initialpageid` to the actual id of you entry page):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#initialpageid", function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".trigger-tennista", function(event){
        var cognome;
        cognome = $(event.target).closest(".trigger-tennista").attr("data-cognome");
        console.log(cognome); // ok fino qui
        $(".single-tennista-container").load("../single-player.html", function(){ // ok caricamento file
            valorijson(cognome);
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

In this way, as you load new pages, the click handler will automatically be bound to new .trigger-tennista elements.

**UPDATE:**

In reviewing your code from the comments, I have found 2 issues:

You are mixing version 1.2 javascript with 1.4 css. Choose one version of jQM, preferably 1.4 (or at least 1.3)

In you code you were setting

```
var popup = $(".single-tennista-container");
```

outside of the click handler, so it could find more than one DIV with this class as pages are added.  Instead get the correct div within the handler:

```
var popup;
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#splashpage", function(){

    $(document).on("click", ".trigger-tennista", function(event){       
        var close = $(".close");
        var cognome;
        cognome = $(event.target).closest(".trigger-tennista").attr("data-cognome");
        popup = $(event.target).closest(".ui-content").find(".single-tennista-container");
        popup.load("single-player.html", function(){ // ok caricamento file
            valorijson(cognome);
            popup.removeClass("outsidepopup").addClass("insidepopup");                    
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
        /*$(".bg-popup").fadeIn(500);*/
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".close", function () {
        popup = $(this).closest(".insidepopup");
        popup.removeClass("insidepopup").addClass("outsidepopup");
      /*$(".bg-popup").fadeOut(500);*/
    });

    initializeisotope();
});
```

Comment: thanks @ezanker, it works like a charm. You made my day :)
Btw, i've still not idea why the console wrote twice each name on the click :/

Comment: @Robert, because you were adding a new handler to all .trigger-tennista elements on each page load. This created a second handler on existing ones when you loaded the second page.

Comment: at the end of the project I'll have more than 30 .trigger-tennista, is there a way to solve this "problem"?

Comment: @Robert, my solution should solve the multiple handlers issue via the event delegation which only adds the handler once when the first page loads. If it is still running twice, maybe change ".trigger-tennista *" to ".trigger-tennista" so event propagation is not making it run twice, and add event.stopPropagation() to the end of the click handler. See updated answer.

Comment: in this way works. I didn't know the function `event.stopPropagation()`, so I discover something new today :) Thanks again mate! (I can't vote up sorry )
ps: I can't tag you :O

Comment: yesterday I thought was solved that BUT I now I added 2 mope pages and I have some `.trigger-tennista` in 3 different pages (now I have index.html + story.html, winners.html, info.html) so the data from json are loaded 3 times! (one for every page). 
any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @Robert, make sure to add the event.stopPropagation() and/or return false at the end of the click handler. Also make sure the click handler is only added once in splashpage, and does not exist in the other HTML pages.

Comment: I've updated the code. Like you can see there is the `event.stopPropagation` at end of click handler. Btw, `#splashpage` is unique and it's in the index.html and it's the # of the main page

Comment: @Robert, maybe I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish and what the problem is...

Comment: I have index + 3 external pages + 1 other page that contain the info of the person, in every page i have the trigger `.trigger-tennista` and when I click on that a div slide in with the content of that person. I works, but I can see the info repeated 3 times ( for example for the name "mike" i see in the div "mikemikemike" like is called 3 times). Is clear now? :)

Comment: @Robert, what if you change $(".cognome").append(tennista.cognome); to $(".cognome").empty().append(tennista.cognome);

Comment: it works on the display but in can still see the function called more than 1 time in the console (I added a console.log to see what happened)

Comment: @Robert, you could try changing $(document).on("click", ".trigger-tennista"... to $(document).one("click", ".trigger-tennista" ... (.one instead of .on) or you could try off() then on():  $(document).off("click").on("click", ".trigger-tennista"...

Comment: thanks for the reply but nothing works :/ 
btw, if you want and **if you have time** I put [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp272vbcapstx4w/ATP%20finals.rar?dl=0) the files so you can see it live

Comment: ps: I tried to change `pagecreate` with `pageshow` but still more than one time

Comment: @Robert, see my updated answer. I think it was the var popup = $(".single-tennista-container"); line which could find multiple divs...

Comment: sorry for the delay but I was busy. This was used to to create a popup with a external page called via ajax but now I change the way to do that using the popup of the framework. And I was close to solve that but like you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702784/strange-behavior-of-popup-in-jquery-mobile) I have another issue :/